# xml manipulation in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file that has contents like the below Want to read the file below as an xml then update the variable without the 2 contents that have the Validate="false" I it. I don't intent to save content of this new xml back.

thanks

only figured out how to parse the contents that are not validate=false

```
$pngXml.NG.DeviceInterfaceLinks.DeviceInterfaceLink | ForEach-Object { if (!$psitem.HasAttribute('Va
lidate')){$psitem} }
```

The actual xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NG>
  <Devices>
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC1" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC2" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC3" Hwku="Test1" />   
  </Devices>
  <DeviceInterfaceLinks>    
    <DeviceInterfaceLink xsi:type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD1" />
    <DeviceInterfaceLink xsi:type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD2" Validate="false" />
    <DeviceInterfaceLink xsi:type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD3"  Validate="false" />
   </DeviceInterfaceLinks>
</NG>
```

end state of variable that is needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NG>
  <Devices>
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC1" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC2" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device xsi:type="Access" Host="ABC3" Hwku="Test1" />   
  </Devices>
  <DeviceInterfaceLinks>    
    <DeviceInterfaceLink xsi:type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD1" />
  </DeviceInterfaceLinks>
</NG>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the output you want:

```
$x = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NG>
  <Devices>
    <Device type="Access" Host="ABC1" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device type="Access" Host="ABC2" Hwku="Test1" />
    <Device type="Access" Host="ABC3" Hwku="Test1" />   
  </Devices>
  <DeviceInterfaceLinks>    
    <DeviceInterfaceLink type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD1" />
    <DeviceInterfaceLink type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD2" Validate="false" />
    <DeviceInterfaceLink type="DeviceInterfaceLink" StartDevice="ABD3"  Validate="false" />
   </DeviceInterfaceLinks>
</NG>'

Foreach ($node in $x.SelectNodes("//DeviceInterfaceLink[@Validate='false']")) {
  $x.SelectNodes("//DeviceInterfaceLinks").removechild($node) | out-null
}

$sw = [System.IO.StringWriter]::new()
$xw = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::new($sw)
$xw.Formatting = "indented"
$x.WriteContentTo($xw)
$xw.flush()
$sw.flush()
$sw.ToString()
```

I chose to store your xml contents in the variable `$x`. I replaced `xsi:type` because it seems unnecessary and my editor did not like the syntax. You can always add it back with a replace operation.

I am selecting the nodes where the DeviceInterfaceLink element contains a Validate attribute that equals false. Then I loop through that collection with a `foreach` and remove those nodes from DeviceInterfaceLinks using `RemoveChild()`.

The `StringWriter` and `XmlTextWriter` objects are for formatting purposes only. Without them, you could simply retrieve the xml string data with `$x.outerxml`. However, you would have no indentations or new lines.